# How to reshuffle in apache beam using spark runner

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I am doing this simulation using the spark runner:

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create();

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(Create.of(1))
 .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Integer, Integer>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void apply(@Element Integer element, OutputReceiver<Integer> outputReceiver) {
                        IntStream.range(0, 4_000_000).forEach(outputReceiver::output);

                    }
                }))
.apply(Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())
.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Integer, Integer>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void apply(@Element Integer element, OutputReceiver<Integer> outputReceiver) {
                        try {
                            // simulate a rpc call of 10ms
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        outputReceiver.output(element);

                    }
                }));
PipelineResult result = p.run();
result.waitUntilFinish();
```

I am running using `--runner=SparkRunner --sparkMaster=local[8]` but only 1 thread is used after the reshuffle.
Why the Rechuffle is not working?

If I change the reshuffle for this:

```
.apply(MapElements.into(kvs(integers(), integers())).via(e -> KV.of(e % 8, e)))
.apply(GroupByKey.create())
.apply(Values.create())
.apply(Flatten.iterables())
```

Then I get 8 thread running.

BR, Rafael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Reshuffle on Beam on Spark boils down to the implementation at

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/spark/translation/GroupCombineFunctions.java#L191

I wonder if in this case both `rdd.context().defaultParallelism()` and `rdd.getNumPartitions()` are 1. I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-10834 to investigate.

In the meantime, you can use GroupByKey to get the desired parallelism as you've indicated. (If you don't literally have integers, you could try using the hash of your element, a Math.random(), or even an incrementing counter as the key).

Comment: Thanks robertwb, I didnt realize about that.  I will play then with the default parallelism option in spark and I will look forward for that bug. The real problem I am having is with TextIO that internally uses that Reshuffle when loading files.